# Python chars compare in if/else

Tags: python

The goal is to get a y or n and do different things based on the if/elseif/else statement. The problem is that it does not see y and n as proper values. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
print 'Are you happy with the final crop?'
happyTest = raw_input('Enter y or n: ')
if happyTest == 'y':
    happy = False
elif happy == 'n':
    padding == int(raw_input('Enter crop padding:'))
else:
    print 'Not a valid input'
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'not seeing y and n as poper values'. What exact input are you giving it and what is the output? Because as coded this should work as long as the user enters exactly 'y' or exactly 'n', but it will fail if say, the user enters `'y  '` or `'Y'` or anything similar (ignoring the obvious typos).

Comment: What if you compare with `happyTest.strip() == "y"` instead? Also, you want to change the second `happy` to `happyTest.strip()`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your problem is? Your `elif` statement should check `happyTest`, not `happy`, and your assignment of `padding` should use only a single equals sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two problems I can see:

1. `elif happy == 'n':` references an undefined variable, `happy`. You meant `happyTest`.
2. `padding == int(raw_input('Enter crop padding:'))` tries to compare `padding` and `int(...)`. You meant to assign. Change `==` to `=`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to icktoofay, who points out some problems in the code that I concur with, you should also probably use `strip` to make sure that the input doesn't have white spaces around it, which would throw off your comparison test.

Alternatively, try a comparison like

```
if "y" in happyTest:
     # then assume they meant "yes"
     # ...
```